# Value of type 'SecondPageController' has no member 'miniView'

Tags: swift, xcode

I got seems similar but little bit different question.
It is about declare size issue, but have small error here.

I think error is related to Main.stroyboard, and tried to change ViewController name and also added 'miniView' to ViewController. 
My error is

"Value of type 'SecondPageController' has no member 'miniView'",

Witch is very common error(I looked many of same question with this format), but I think my error is relate to adding some new view or something.

And here is my code.

```
class SecondPageController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!

var imageArray = [UIImage]()

var currentPage = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

imageArray = [UIImage(named: "bus1")!, UIImage(named: "bus2")!]

for i in 0..<imageArray.count {

let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = imageArray[i]
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
let xPosition = self.miniView.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)

mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

}

Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(startAnimating), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func startAnimating() {

//that line check if the current page is the last one, and set it to the first, otherwise, it increment the currentPage
self.currentPage = (self.currentPage == imageArray.count-1) ? 0 : self.currentPage+1


var newOffset = mainScrollView.contentOffset
newOffset.x = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(self.currentPage)

self.mainScrollView.setContentOffset(newOffset, animated: true)
}

}
```

I expecting add something to this error solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no member `miniView` in `SecondPageController`. The error was very precise.

If you wanna use a component named `miniView` you need a reference to it, you can use 2 approaches:

**1 - Storyboard:**

Drag a view to your `UIViewController` and link it to `@IBOutlet weak var miniView: UIView!`

---

**2 - Programatic:**

Instantiate it like: `let miniView = UIView()`

---

Since you are using Storyboards, you probably forgot to add an `@IBOutlet`to that view, so use approach 1.

Comment: Yes you were right! I didn't add that link.
Also I got problem, when I added link, there were only "miniView" type I can choose. which goes 

**"@IBOutlet weak var miniView: miniView!"**. 

But when I forced to change to 

**"@IBOutlet weak var miniView: UIView!"** , 

It works! Thank you!